# query Google for a business open hours

Tags: android

I was wondering if it was possible to query Google for the opening hours of a business listed in maps, in the sane way one can query location information of said business. For example if I wanted my app to tell me when WalMart was open, how could I query Google to return just the opening hours?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356538/api-for-getting-business-hours-at-a-location