# Unable to get special opening hours from Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-search, google-my-business-api

Special hours are marketed/documented on **Google My Business**, see https://support.google.com/business/answer/6303076

Is there a way of retrieve this special opening hours from the Google Places API?

I've tried adding special hours to Google My Business. It works as expected in Google Maps and Google search. However, it does not show in the returned values from Google Places API.

Comment: what are your business details? I can look into this for you

Answer (score 5):

Currently, special hours are not available via Places API.

There is a [feature request 10145](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10145) in the public issue tracker to add this information in the API.

Please star the public issue to vote for this feature and receive further updates.

Comment: The feature request has been implemented per [comment #88](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829064#comment88).

Answer (score 2):

For people looking for an answer to this, there is a solution and that is to use Google My Business API. There you can get special hours.
Google My Business API you have to apply to use. Read more at [Google My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business)

Comment: Can you only use Google My Business for a business you manage. For example could I use this api to get information about other businesses

Comment: Hi! You can only do it for business you control and manage. (at least what i have seen)